# Why does my pilot light go out when the main burner shuts off?

Tags: water-heater

My water heater pilot light goes out every time the main burner shuts off.

I have replaced the pilot assembly with new thermal couple gas lines to the control and pilot (the assembly came all together as one unit to install in the water heater).

However, I'm still having the same problem so I replaced the main control on the water heater, but that didn't help. I've still got the same problem: pilot light will light, the burner will come on and heat up, but when it shuts off, the pilot light goes out as well every time.

What else should I look at to fix this?

Comment: can we have 2 pictures please, one with and one without pilot light burning

Comment: Make/model of the water heater?

Comment: Some punctuation & capitalisation, or even paragraphs, might help to turn this run-on stream-of-consciousness into something readable.

Comment: That was _very_ difficult to read and understand. I've edited your question to try to make it more readable. Please confirm that it still adequately states the situation and asks the question you want to ask (I don't think you care if anyone else has had the problem, which is what you asked with a question mark, what you want to ask is how to fix it). If I've misedited it and changed your intent or misstated facts, please [edit] again to clarify. Also, include the brand & model of the water heater in question as that will help the experts here help you.

Comment: Usually replacing parts to find the problem gets expensive fast.  Should try to find out why the pilot keeps going out, might just be windy.  Have a propane furnace/heater with though the wall vent, the wind hits the vent just right and blows out the pilot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Replacing the thermal couple and cleaning the burner assembly did not fix the issue. Replacing the gas line pressure regulator fixed it.

Of course I only figured that out after I replaced the water heater and the new one had the same issue!